# Non-const copy constructor compiles fine with C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, language-lawyer, copy-constructor

I'd like to find out why the code below doesn't compile with C++14, but compiles fine with C++17. Any ideas what could be changed since C++17? The thing is of course about non-const copy constructor of a class A. I am using VS 2019. Is this code valid at all?

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A() { }
    A(A& a) { }
};

A fun() {
    A a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    A a = fun();
}
```

Messages from the compiler:

1. class A has no suitable copy constructor
2. initializing cannot convert from A to A
3. Cannot copy construct class A due to ambiguous copy constructors or no available copy constructor

Comment: One problem is that MSVC since long have an extension that allows temporaries to be bound by non-constant references.

Comment: Probably this is because of [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) since C++17

Comment: @dewaffled I don't think so, as this is a case of *N*RVO where copy elision is not mandatory.

Comment: please include the error message in the question

Comment: its the same with gcc and clang: https://godbolt.org/z/xP3hdWxrr

Comment: It would help slightly with answering to use different names for the two variables, instead of calling them both `a`

Comment: @Jodocus copy-elision is not only a thing in return statements, the rules regarding it when initializing an object was also updated in c++17. That's the part that's relevant here.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/fYnvorsq9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fun()` is a prvalue of type `A`, so `A a = fun();` means that `a` is the result object of the function call,  there is no intermediate temporary.

The text for this is in C++17 [basic.lval]/2:

> The *result object* of a prvalue is the object initialized
> by the prvalue;

It would be the same for `A a = A(A(A(A(A(fun())))));` etc.  - all of the prvalues have `a` as their result object.

The behaviour of the return statement is in [stmt.return]/2:

> the `return` statement initializes the glvalue result or prvalue result object of the (explicit or implicit) function
> call by copy-initialization (11.6) from the operand.

The result object can be initialized successfully by copy-initialization from `a` (the local variable of `fun`) because that is a non-const lvalue and so the copy constructor taking non-const lvalue reference does bind to it.

---

Prior to C++17 `fun()`'s return value was a temporary object, and then main's `a` was copy/move-constructed from the temporary,  with elision being optional (but the valid constructor was required to exist).

Comment: _the `return` statement initializes the glvalue result ...  of the (explicit or implicit) function call_ Together with [expr.call]/9 saying _The result of a function call is the result of the possibly-converted operand of the `return` statement_, this means that `return` statement initializes its operand (result thereof) from its operand. That's why we love C++.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Yeah I think that sentence from [stmt.return]/2 is a bit defective but the intent seems clear